# How to translate this formula translated into VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this formula below that I am attempting to use to perform different calculations depending on the data in the referenced cells. The formula works, but I need to have more flexibility on the data found.

```
=IF(AND(U1="APO 300%",$E2="P+"),P2-(SUMIF($F$2:$F$74,300%,H$2:H$74)*M2)-(SUMIF($F$2:$F$74,150%,H$2:H$74)*M2),IF(AND(U1="APO 300%",$E2="P"),H2,""))
```

Is there a code that can duplicate this?

Comment: Yep, using `Range` and a bunch of `If..Then..Else..End If` type statements.  But [so] isn't a free code writing service, it's expected that you have tried to do this before you ask for help.  Please read [ask] and show what you have tried yourself before asking for help

Comment: It will translate to a similar looking code, if range("U1")="APO" and range("e2").value="P+") then...... look at, using logic statements in VBA, I think looking at it, you may be able to use IIF.  Fully agree with Dave, you need to have a go.....

Answer (score 0):

Worksheets have an `Evaluate` method which can be used to do what you want:

```
shtObject.Evaluate("A1+B1") '<<< substitute in your formula
```